# Randomly select objects

Tags: javascript

My goal is to get a random object based on a few parameters insignificant to this question.

```
function CreateObject(name) = {
this.name = name
};

var bob = CreateObject("Bob");
var john = CreateObject("John");
var rob = CreateObject("Rob");
var steven = CreateObject("Steven");
```

Do I need to insert each object into an array, or is there a better way of doing this if I have 100+ objects?

Comment: go on, throw it into an array, you can do it

Comment: Should that be, for instance, `var bob = CreateObject("Bob");` ?

Comment: Why was my question modified so the CreateObject was removed before the ("Bob")?

Comment: Still not quite right (and my comment was off too.)  With this code, you probably need `var bob = new CreateObject("Bob");`  Otherwise you're setting the name on the global object (perhaps the window.)

Comment: You don't have to pre-initialize these objects if it's possible to create the random object based on the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these objects are created but never destroyed, you can have the constructor function maintain an array for you and hook a random function into that:

```
var CreateObject = (function() {
    var created = [];
    var CreateObject = function(name) {
        this.name = name;
        created.push(this);
    };
    CreateObject.random = function() {
        return created[Math.floor(created.length * Math.random())];
    }
    return CreateObject;
}())

var bob = new CreateObject("Bob");
var john = new CreateObject("John");
var rob = new CreateObject("Rob");
var steven = new CreateObject("Steven");

CreateObject.random();  // CreateObject {name: "Rob"}
CreateObject.random();  // CreateObject {name: "Steven"}
CreateObject.random();  // CreateObject {name: "Rob"}
CreateObject.random();  // CreateObject {name: "John"}
// etc.
```

This technique could also be extended to allow for deletion, but you would have to somehow explicitly tell the constructor function that the objects are being deleted.  Otherwise, not only would your random function not work properly, but you'd have a memory leak as well.

(Note that it's not precisely the constructor function which stores the array.  It's stored in a closure that the constructor function has access to.)

Answer (score 2):

The most used, simple and efficient(?) solution is to store everything on an array, then pick up a random index.